# How to submit my first program to SPOJ platform? Why I am getting time limit exceeded or runtime error NZEC?

Tags: java, netbeans

My problem is given as [CODESPTB ON SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CODESPTB/).
My program is working correctly on my IDE NetBeans but when I am submitting this program on SPOJ it is not submitting correctly.

It is saying time limit exceeded or sometimes it is saying Runtime Error NZEC.

```
         public class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
         java.util.Scanner s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        //System.out.println(s.hasNext());
        //if(s.hasNext()){
        int firstLine=s.nextInt();
        int[][] finalArray=new int[firstLine][];
        for(int i=0;i<firstLine;i++){
        /* if(s.hasNextInt()){*/  int secondLine= s.nextInt();
           int[] thirdLineArray=new int[secondLine];

           for(int j=0;j<secondLine;j++){
               thirdLineArray[j]=s.nextInt();
           }
           finalArray[i]=thirdLineArray;

        }
        //}
        PassingMultiDimArray(finalArray);
//       for(int[] x:finalArray){
//           System.out.println();
//           for(int y:x){
//               System.out.print(y+" ");
//           }
//       }
        //}    

    }

    private static void PassingMultiDimArray(int[][] finalArray) {
    for(int i=0;i<finalArray.length;i++){
        countSwapInsertSort(finalArray[i]);
    }
    }

    private static void countSwapInsertSort(int[] a) {
    //    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
   // int a[]={14,44,37,20,43,20,33,55};
    int swap=0; 
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
    for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
        if(a[j]<a[j-1]){
            int temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j-1];
            a[j-1]=temp;
            swap++;
        }
        else break;
    }
}

     //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
     System.out.println(swap);

    }

}
```

Please tell my mistake, how to submit this problem on SPOJ corectly?

[image: ScreenShot on Spoj]

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
    if(a[j]<a[j-1]){
        int temp=a[j];
        a[j]=a[j-1];
        a[j-1]=temp;
        swap++;
    }
    else break;
}
```

High time complexity O(n2)

Comment: @basycal what is solution of this high time complexity